# Can you increase network to a specific device through a modem?

Tags: networking, windows-10

As the title states, is there a way to increase network to a specific computer/cpu from a modem? If there is, please elaborate thoroughly. I'm not a computer wiz. I have Windows 10 Home. It is brand new, less than a week but I have had numerous other computers. I'd be happy to provide further details if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "increase network"?  If two computers are connected together then you have **a** network, but it is a singular item and you cannot increase it.  What exactly are you wanting to increase?  Do you mean the speed (bandwidth) between the two devices or give priority to a particular device?

Comment: Your question is very vague... I am assuming you mean to increase the network *SPEED* to a specific computer, then we would need to know more about your setup, modem, switch, router, number of network hosts, types of connections (WiFi, Ethernet, type/speed of connection), ISP connection, and what you REALLY hope to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "increasing network" I assume that you want to increase the speed of the network, and further more increase the MB/s that you are able to download (or KB/s). Well, as others stated everything starts with the bandwidth that you are given by you ISP. If it is a 50 mbits per second, 24, 10, etc. After you know that, you can use QoS or Quality of Service in order to allocate the bandwidth that you want to certain services. Let's say, that you are streaming video via HTTP, and another home member is downloading a file via FTP, and another one is making a skype call via VoIP. First of all, you have to think which of these activities is the most important. Do you want the skype call to have zero latency ? Then you give 60% of your overall bandwidth to VoIP...is downloading the file via the FTP top priority ? Then you give the FTP 90% of your bandwidth and let the VoIP call and the streaming hiccup a little.

QoS is something that most routers support nowadays...you just have to go to the router web interface and make the appropriate configurations.

I hope I understood your question. (remember, everything depends on your ISP and your wiring...[fiber, copper wires, etc...])